# Import "requests" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource (module) requests

Tags: python-requests, pylance

I am having an error while importing the library `request`:

```
Import "requests" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource (module) requests
```

In addition, `flask`, `flask_restful` and `pandas` are not working too, however, `random` works fine.
How should I fix this error?
Thanks.
Here's an example below:

```
      import requests 
      x = input("write a file copy path: ")
      f = open(x, "r")
      lines = f.readlines()
      fixed_websites = []
      for website in lines:
          fixed_website = website.strip("\n")
          fixed_websites.append(fixed_website)
          print(fixed_websites)
      for site in fixed_websites:
          r = requests.get(f"https://{site}")
          print(f"the content of: {site} is {r.content}")
          if r.status_code != 200:
              print(f"Error: bad status_code for site: {site}, status_code {r.status_code}")
      close(x, "r")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
pip uninstall requests
```

then

```
pip install requests
```

next time you'll import 'requests' you shouldn't have any problems

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).